# what does the log directory consists of?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey ,I m beginner to the ROS . After running nodes earlier , I got some .log files in log directory . I want to know what is it basically . What info it consists ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316928/what-does-the-log-directory-consists-of-??/) by [charvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33083/charvi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2019-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you walking through the tutorials? That's a great way to learn and you will quickly come across the use of some logging statements like ROSINFO in c++ or rospy.loginfo in python.

The output form these messages can end up several places depending on your configuration etc.

Have a look at the introduction pages:

- https://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging
- https://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Logging

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2019-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33083/charvi/) on 2019-03-03**:
Thank you.